# Stuck in a quit or buy Adobe Reader loop

Tags: windows, windows-10, adobe-reader

It's very literally a new e-mail account and even a new user on the computer, but am stuck in a loop with Adobe Reader:

[image: Trial window]

with the options being to quit, buy or start a trial. I've not used Adobe Reader on this computer, have never on any computer under any account ever started a trial or anything like that with them.

How do I just use Adobe Reader?

Normally I'm on Linux but recall using Adobe Reader without every getting stuck in this loop. I have admin priveleges. OS is:

[image: winver]

Comment: This is not happening on any of my Reader machines.  Uninstall Adobe Reader, restart, install again and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: You don't have [Adobe Reader](https://get.adobe.com/reader/), you apparently have Adobe Acrobat, their PDF creator.

Comment: The error message says "Adobe Acrobat", so it seems you do have it installed. It's possible that it was installed during the installation of another product that contained it as a secondary package, so you don't know about it. It's easy enough to check in "Programs and Features" if it's installed.

Comment: Adobe Reader is free as it was kind of mentioned above. Now you need to clarify - do you have problems launching the free version or do you want to install Adobe Acrobat and that is keeping you in a loop?

Comment: "How do I just use Adobe Reader?" - You would have to install it.  Your screenshot indicates you have a expired trial installation of Adobe Acrobat installed. Adobe Acrobat is paid software, once the trial period is over for any user on the machine, you must purchase it. As this is clearly the case, of you having ran the wrong piece of software, I am voting to close this question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user has Adobe Acrobat installed not Adobe Reader.  Adobe Acrobat is paid software so the only way to run it, after the trial has expired on the machine, is to purchase Adobe Acrobat. This is clearly a case of the author installing the wrong software but asking about a difference piece of software.

Comment: Extra note: If you install Adobe Acrobat PRO next to Adobe Acrobat Reader, PRO will replace reader, and reader cannot be used anymore. It automatically launches pro.

Answer (score 3):

Adobe Acrobat is NOT Adobe Reader.

Acrobat is for creating PDFs and is expensive.

Reader is free and is for reading PDFs.

You should uninstall Adobe Acrobat, then go back to the Adobe site, and I suggest looking more carefully at their products and then download the free Reader.

Or, unless you're actually really attached to Reader, I suggest either using one of the browsers on your computer to open PDFs, they can all do it just fine, or another PDF reader that isn't so bloated and dysfunctional as Adobe Reader is.